# put path of a file in a string in python

Tags: python

i want to put a path in a string but in some places like some where have \n in the path i give an error

code:
import pygame

```
pygame.init()
icon = 'C:\Users\treed\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1'
pygame.image.load(icon)
```

and the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\treed\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\pythaon - Copy.py", line 4
    icon = 'C:\Users\treed\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1'
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Process finished with exit code 1
```

how can i put path in a string?

Comment: 'C:\\Users\\treed\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1' try this it depends which os you are using.

Comment: `r'C:\Users\treed\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1'` or `'C:/Users/treed/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1'` or `'C:\\Users\\treed\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1'` - see [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe?

```
icon = "C:\\Users\\treed\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1"
pygame.image.load(icon)
```